# Deserialization error in a new environment

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I have a web application that calls a third-party web service. When I run it locally, I have no problems, but when I move it to my production environment, I get the following error:

There is an error in XML document (2, 428).
Stack:
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at RMXClasses.RMXContactService.ContactService.getActiveSessions(String user, String pass) in C:\Users\hp\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ReklamStore\RMXClasses\Web References\RMXContactService\Reference.cs:line 257 at

I have used the same web config file from the production environment but it still works locally. My local machine is a running vista home edition and the production environment is windows server 2003. The application is written in asp.net 3.5, wierdly under the asp.net config tab in iis, 3.5 doesn't show up in the drop down list, although that version of the framework is installed. The error is not being thrown in my code, it happens during serialization. I called the method on the proxy, I have checked the arguments and they are OK. I have also logged the SOAP request and response, and they both look OK as well. I am really at a loss here. Any ideas?

SOAP log: This is the soap response that the program seems to have trouble parsing only on server 2003. On my machine the soap is identical, and yet it parses with no problems.

SoapResponse BeforeDeserialize;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:ContactService" xmlns:ns2="http://api.yieldmanager.com/types" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getActiveSessionsResponse>
<sessions SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:session[1]" xsi:type="ns2:array_of_session">
<item xsi:type="ns2:session">
<token xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1ae12517584b</token>
<creation_time xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2009-09-25T05:51:19Z</creation_time>
<modification_time xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2009-09-25T05:51:19Z</modification_time>
<ip_address xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxxxxxx</ip_address>
<contact_id xsi:type="xsd:long">xxxxxx</contact_id></item></sessions>
</ns1:getActiveSessionsResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: is .net 3.5 installed on the prod. server?

Comment: Pull out the response XML and post here what's at `(2, 428)`, this ought to help us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yes, 3.5 is installed.

See soap log below

Comment: Weirdly, when I publish the site in debug mode, the error goes away. I guess that's what I'll do for now, but I'd really like to know what's happening here!

Comment: Had a similar issue, mine turned out to be a Application pool issue. I created and used the same application pool settings in my new environment, and voila.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running [Aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx) ?

> When multiple versions of the .NET
>   Framework are executing side-by-side
>   on a single computer, the ASP.NET
>   ISAPI version mapped to an ASP.NET
>   application determines which version
>   of the common language runtime (CLR)
>   is used for the application. The
>   ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool
>   (Aspnet_regiis.exe) allows an
>   administrator or installation program
>   to easily update the script maps for
>   an ASP.NET application to point to the
>   ASP.NET ISAPI version that is
>   associated with the tool. The tool can
>   also be used to display the status of
>   all installed versions of ASP. NET,
>   register the ASP.NET version that is
>   coupled with the tool, create
>   client-script directories, and perform
>   other configuration operations.

Answer (score 0):

The .Net versions listed in the ASP.Net in IIS show the versions of the CLR installed. .Net 3 and 3.5 still use version 2 of the CLR, they just added extra classes for WCF, Linq, etc.

As far as the actual problem goes, are you perhaps running debug code on the Vista machine and release code on the production one? Are there any differences in the build? Are all the assemblies in the same kind of places on both environments?

Comment: Wait a sec, I see what you mean. yes, I am running in debug mode locally, and a using release publication on the server.

Comment: Just ran it in release mode locally, and no problem.